# How to connect to a remote mysql hosting from docker container?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, docker, dockerfile

I have a remote mysql hosting.

I have created a simple spring boot app.

I have created a .jar file of this project.

I have created a docker image from this app.jar

I have created a container which use this hosting. Everything works ok but **THE PROBLEM is**:

It use the parameters supplied in my config file.

Using this works ok with the parameters supplied in class file:

```
docker run  --name app1 -p 8000:8080 app-image:v1
```

What I need to do is connect to a random hosting provided when I create a container and not be linked (or coupled) to this specific server.

Here the steps:

1.- Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8
VOLUME /tmp
EXPOSE 8080:8080
ADD ./target/app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]
```

2.- Create image

```
docker build -t app-image:v1 .
```

3.- Create a container

```
docker run  --name app1 -p 8000:8080 app-image:v1
```

Works ok, ***but use the parameters in DatasourceConfig***

4.- My configuration in spring boot app (v2.4.3) is like this:

```
@Configuration
public class DatasourceConfig {
    @Bean
    public DataSource datasource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create()
          .driverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver")
          .url("jdbc:mysql://mysql-remote.net:8192/test-database")
          .username("root")
          .password("q")
          .build(); 
    }
}
```

I have tried several options to override the default options, like this:

```
docker run  --name app1 -p 8001:8080 -e MYSQL_USER=root -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=q  -e MYSQL_DATABASE=jdbc:mysql://mysql-remote.net:8192/test-database app-image:v1
```

but I get:

```
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

UPDATE 1:
Working on local I use this configuration:

```
 @Bean
    public DataSource datasource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create()
          .driverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver")
          .url("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test-database?serverTimezone=UTC&CuseLegacyDatetimeCode=false")
          .username("root")
          .password("q")
          .build(); 
    }
```

I create docker image with this configuration. As I know passing parameters  should overwrite this configuration, but no way.

I have used what Ashok  wrote, but it doesn't work.

UPDATE 2 (RESOLVED)

Added this code in DatasourceConfig, using default values to work in local:

```
    @Value("${custom.property.url:jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test-database?serverTimezone=UTC&CuseLegacyDatetimeCode=false}")
    String url;

    @Value("${custom.property.username:root}")
    String username;

    @Value("${custom.property.password:q}")
    String password;
    
    @Bean
    public DataSource datasource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create()
          .driverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver")
          .url(url)
          .username(username)
          .password(password)
          .build(); 
    }
}
```

Later I create the image as usually and I run the container like this (overwriting the parameters and connecting to an external mysql hosting FROM my docker container). I tested the app with several containers and it works great!!

```
docker run --name app1 -p 8001:8080 -e custom.property.username=root -e custom.property.password=q  -e custom.property.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test-database?serverTimezone=UTC&CuseLegacyDatetimeCode=false app-image:v1
```

thanks for the help!!

Comment: Why do you have this class DatasourceConfig and don't use default?

Comment: Why build your own data source? Why not use JPA and env settings?

Comment: Not working application.properties in version 2.4.3 of spring boot, that the reason

Answer (score 1):

It should be: `SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL`, `MYSQL_USER`, `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD`.

Answer (score 0):

```
docker run  --name app1 -p 8001:8080 -e MYSQL_USER=root -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=q  -e SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:mysql://mysql-remote.net:8192/test-database app-image:v1
```

Comment: Can you please add some explaination to your code? [Code-only answers may fall under 'Very Low Quality' ...and are candidates for deletion....We've always touted that we aren't a code factory. We are the people who teach others to fish. Code-only answers only feed a person for a day](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272/is-there-any-benefit-to-allowing-code-only-answers-while-blocking-code-only-ques)

Comment: Delete it if you want

Answer (score 0):

Try with below configurations

**Docker/Linux Terminal:**

```
docker run --name dreamsql -p 3306:3306 \
-e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mypwd \
-e MYSQL_USER=myuser \
-e MYSQL_PASSWORD=<Password> \
-e MYSQL_DATABASE=mydata \
-d mysql:5.7
```

**Windows CMD Prompt:**

```
docker run --name dreamsql -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mypwd -e MYSQL_USER=myuser -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=<Password> -e MYSQL_DATABASE=mydata -d mysql:5.7
```

**CHECK_BELOW** should be replaced by one from below based on your requirement:

- localhost for docker desktop
- 192.168.99.100 for docker toolbox
- IP address for Remote MySQL instance

  "jdbc:mysql://<CHECK_BELOW>:3306/mydata"

**Note**: username (**MYSQL_USER**): myuser and password (**MYSQL_PASSWORD**) as used in MySQL docker command